# SSRS: Pictures and graphs

Tags: sql-server, reporting-services, ssrs-2008, report

I have a report that for some parameters it doesn´t show the pictures and graphs. But if I execute the report in VS (Preview) it works perfectly.

In the screenshot below I highlight in red how the graphs and pictures look like.
[image: Screenshot]

Do you have any idea where can I start looking for the solution??

Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

This has to do with the path you specify for the images. The report is in a different location once you load it into Report Manager. There are a few different solutions to this problem depending on your preferences.

1. Add the image in the Report Data section. This will embed the image in the .rdl file.
2. Encode the image in the database and have it selected in a dataset.
3. Use a relative path that points to a folder in Report Manager.

The third option is the one I prefer. I have an Images folder in Report Manager with my images. In the report I use a reference like this:

[image]

In this example, the file name is Blue.png

Comment: Hi Steven. Thanks for your reply. The problem is that it also happen with some graphs and only for some specific parameters values. If I change the values then it works. Another detail is that those graphs are in a subreport. If I execute the subreport with the same parameters then it works, but when I call it from the main report it doen't show the pictures. Any idea? Thanks a lot!

Comment: Are you testing the subreport on the Report Manager, or just previewing in SSRS? Double check how the parameters are passed to the subreport, make sure they all match up correctly and are all populated.

Comment: Hi Steven, The subreport works fine in both. The main report works fine in the local VS buy it doesn't in the Report Manager. Thanks!! Carlos